# Kotlin: Collection of functions with similar signatures

Tags: generics, collections, kotlin

I'm going to have a class, than can emmit events of different types. I need to store listeners for this events.

Code will look like

```
open class EventEmitter(
        var maxListeners: Int = defaultMaxListeners
) {

    private val listeners: MutableMap<String, TODO> = mutableMapOf()

    fun <T> on(event: String, listener: (T) -> Unit){
        listeners.set(event,listener)
    }

    fun <T> emit(event: String, arg: T): Boolean = TODO()
```

what should I use instead of TODO? Does there are any others ways to store similar functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these functions are all of type `(T) -> Unit` you can use this directly:

```
open class EventEmitter<T>(var maxListeners: Int = 5) {

    private val listeners: MutableMap<String, (T) -> Unit> = mutableMapOf()

    fun on(event: String, listener: (T) -> Unit) {
        listeners.set(event, listener)
    }

    fun emit(event: String, arg: T): Boolean = TODO()
}
```

Note that I moved the generic type `T` to the class directly.

**EDIT:**

Since you don't accept the EventEmitter to be generic, you'll need to do some unsafe casting:

```
typealias Event<T> = (T) -> Unit

open class EventEmitter(var maxListeners: Int = 5) {

    private val listeners: MutableMap<String, Event<*>> = mutableMapOf()

    fun <T> on(event: String, listener: Event<T>) {
        listeners[event] = listener
    }

    fun <T> emit(event: String, arg: T): Boolean {
        val listener = listeners[event] as Event<T>
        listener(arg)
        TODO()
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that EventEmitter must be not generic

Comment: Okay that's unfortunate. I've editted the answer accordingly